# Populating entites in Nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate

can anyone help me with some idea? below is my question.
Assume that am having a entity named A with fields A1, A2, A3 and A4 and also i have 3 Stored procedures which returns data from table A alone.

(Note: Table A has Only 4 columns A1, A2, A3, A4).

First Stored procedure returning A1, A2
Second Stored procedure return A1, A2, A3
Third Stored procedure returns A1 alone .

For the above scenario do i need to create three different mapping or is there any work around?How to handle this scenario with single entity A and with less change code.......

**MY SCENARIO:**

```
public IList<Userdatasw> Find(string userName)
        {
            var s = ServiceLocator.Resolve<IeGoatSessionFactory>().OpenSession();

            // Executing the stored procedure 
            IList userList1 = s.CreateSQLQuery("exec dbo.IFSEntry @UserName=:UserName")
                .AddScalar("Password", NHibernateUtil.String)
                .AddScalar("UserLevel", NHibernateUtil.Int32)
                .AddScalar("UserName", NHibernateUtil.String)
                .AddScalar("EmployeeId", NHibernateUtil.String)
                .AddScalar("SenAccntManager", NHibernateUtil.String)
                .AddScalar("updaterequired", NHibernateUtil.String)
                .SetParameter("UserName", userName).List();

            // Trying to cast anonymous type to Userdatasw
            IList<Userdatasw> userdatasw1 = userList1.OfType<Userdatasw>().ToList();
            return userdatasw1;

        }
```

In the above code the return type is Ilist but i need to convert it to Userdatasw with less changes in code.
And i have seen many links to explain "populating entites from Stored procedure" in Nhiberante, but i have entity with 20 fields and in the above SP am returning only 6 values.

So for every SP which returns of same type we need to create seperate mapping?

Any idea will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Venkatesh. J

Answer (score 0):

Hi all i have got the solution. Its simple if we use SetResultTransformer.

```
    public IList<Userdatasw> Find(string userName)
    {
        var s = ServiceLocator.Resolve<IeGoatSessionFactory>().OpenSession();

        IQuery query = s.CreateSQLQuery("exec dbo.IFSEntry @UserName=:UserName")
                          .AddScalar("Password", NHibernateUtil.String)
                          .AddScalar("UserLevel", NHibernateUtil.Int32)
                          .AddScalar("UserName", NHibernateUtil.String)
                          .AddScalar("EmployeeId", NHibernateUtil.String)
                          .AddScalar("SenAccntManager", NHibernateUtil.String)
                          .AddScalar("updaterequired", NHibernateUtil.String)
                          .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean(typeof(Userdatasw)))
                          .SetParameter("UserName", userName);
        return query.List<Userdatasw>();
    }
```